# Index shared by two different websites but with different permissions

Tags: algolia

I have an index in Algolia and two websites. As example, the record is:

```
[{
    name: "record 1",
    public: 1
}, {
    name: "record 2",
    public: 0
}]
```

Those two websites search into the same index, but what I want is:

- the first website can search for all records
- the second website should search **only** for `public: 1` and **shouldn't be able** to search for `public: 0`

I thought about two different indexes, but the record with `public: 1` are shared by the two websites, so I should have duplicated records (and, for each plan, there is the limit for records). It's not a solution that I want to apply.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [secured API key](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys/#secured-api-keys) for the second website that contains a filter for `public:1`.

From the docs about secured API keys:

> The goal of a secured API key is to ensure a set of query parameters
>   cannot be changed by the end user. In order to do that, we compute a
>   HMAC SHA-256 hash between one of your API keys that is used as a
>   secret and the set of query parameters you want to enforce.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you!